# creating a regular link for custom wordpress post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a link to the admin menu of an existing plugin. This link should point to a script on the server that downloads a csv file from the server.

I added the line - ***'all_items' => __( 'Download Donors', 'pfund' ),*** and the Download Donors option appeared in the menu. Currently the item points to edit.php. **How do I get this link to point to the plugin folder where the csv generating script is located?**

```
$campaign_def = array(
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => 'pfund_campaign',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => $pfund_options['campaign_slug'],
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => __( 'Campaigns', 'pfund' ),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Campaigns', 'pfund' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Campaign', 'pfund' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New Campaign', 'pfund' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Campaign', 'pfund' ),
            'download_donors' => __( 'Download Donors', 'pfund' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'Download Donors', 'pfund' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Campaign', 'pfund' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Campaign', 'pfund' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Campaigns', 'pfund' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Campaigns Found', 'pfund' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Campaigns Found In Trash', 'pfund' ),
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title'
        ),
        'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_post' => 'edit_campaign'
        ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'pfund_campaign', $campaign_def );
    register_post_type( 'pfund_campaign_list' );
```

Answer (score 0):

do not double post again, please.

try this:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions','download_donors', 10, 2);

function download_donors($actions, $post){
    //check for your post type
    if ($post->post_type =="pfund_campaign"){
        //remove the default edit
        unset($actions['edit']);
        //set new action
        $actions['download_donors'] = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Download Donors</a>';
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: nothing changed, i should also point out that the item appears because of the "'all_items' => __( 'Download Donors', 'pfund' )," and not the "'download_donors' => __( 'Download Donors', 'pfund' )," like I intend, not sure why this is...